# IIS7.5 - Handling static files requests in MVC ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7.5, asp.net-mvc-routing

I would like to handle all the web requests with MVC ASP.NET, but I can't handle any image request for example.

When I created the MVC project, Visual Studio add three ExtensionlessUrlHandler for classic/integrated modes in the web.config, then I add a wildcard mapping in IIS with path equals to "*", using the IsapiModule.

Despite that, everywhen I request an image file (e.g. http://mydomain.com/customer/test.png) the web request hit the StaticFileModule, not the IsapiModule.

I tried also to add the "runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests" flag set to true in the module section, but it doesn't work!

Thanks in advance for any reply,

Fabio

Comment: Err...why would you want to voluntarily add unnecessary overhead to each request and limit the actual response times and throughput of your IIS server by doing this?

Comment: I need to handle this kind of request (especially images) in ASP.NET for authorization issues, I have to check if the user can see that content against the databse.